# ExpressJS: How to render a new webpage after POST request

Tags: node.js, http, express, post

I am making a web app and I want to render a new web page after a POST request (specifically, a confirmation page confirming that the user has been registered). Currently, the code for my post request looks like this:

```
 app.post('/participants/add', (req, res) => {
  mm.addParticipant(req.body, (err, success) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Something went wrong on our end');
    } else {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'confirmation.html'));
    }
  });
});
```

The `res.sendFile()` line currently just sends the `html` code, but the webpage does not render on the response. How do I automatically render the response object as html when it is returned?

Answer (score 0):

I see from the tags that you are using angular(?) So maybe, sending `html` down the wire is not really the best way to do this. I would suggest you send some kind of success/error message and handle the routing on the client.

Comment: So would this mean just using `window.location` or Angular's `$location` on the client? Which do you recommend?

Comment: Use the `$location` service but don't forget to set up a `confirmation` route as well.